# Ошибка синтаксиса python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-2.7

Господа, помогите понять, в чем ошибка.
При попытке запуска скрипта получаю ошибку:

```
  File "./submit_script.py", line 10
    "timeout": (None, "600"),
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Код скрипта:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests

HEADERS = {"Authorization": "Bearer S4MPL3"}

# Submit one or more files.
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8090/tasks/create/submit", files=[
    ("files", open("/home/Downloads/downloader.js", "rb")),
#    ("files", open("2.exe", "rb")),
    "timeout": (None, "600"),
], headers=HEADERS)

# Add your code to error checking for r.status_code.

submit_id = r.json()["submit_id"]
task_ids = r.json()["task_ids"]
errors = r.json()["errors"]
```

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: У вас там ведь список, а не словарь, поэтому и ругается на двоеточние. Кст, таймаут точно не в параметрах `port` указывать, типа: `timeout=(None, 600)`?

Comment: @gil9red Можете поподробнее? Куда по Вашему необходимо переписать таймаут?
Что может решить эту проблему? Просто заменить мою строку на Вашу - не прокатывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"timeout": (None, "600")` это семантика объявления значений в словаре, типа `{"timeout": (None, "600")}`, но у вас тот кусок кода находится внутри списка, поэтому и ругается интерпретатор

Попробуйте так:

```
# Submit one or more files.
r = requests.post(
    "http://localhost:8090/tasks/create/submit", 
    files=[
        ("files", open("/home/Downloads/downloader.js", "rb")),
    ], 
    headers=HEADERS, 
    timeout=(None, 600)
)
```